# Is it okay to use apostrophe's in the URL? Are there any negative consequences?

Tags: seo, url

In particular I'm interested in any SEO consequences.

Comment: http://www.i-com.net/blog/seo-and-apostrophes-a-copywriters-tale-537/ <SEO insight

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442421/apostrophes-in-the-url-good-idea-or-bad-idea-and-why

Comment: It's not okay to use apostrophes in the word 'apostrophes'....

Answer (score 2):

Don't use them. Stick purely to A-Za-z0-9 and _ .  (There are some other characters you can use, but they are reserved and have special meaning).

Comment: ...and the hyphen (`-`)